# cmake include external library

Tags: c++, cmake

I have 2 static libraries `A:\\A.lib`, `B:\\B.lib` I want to link to using MSVS2019

This is my cmakelists.txt

```
add_executable(main ${src}/main.c)
SET(A "A:/")
SET(B "B:/")

find_library(AA "${A}/A.lib")
find_library(BB "${B}/B.lib")
target_link_libraries(main ${AA})
target_link_libraries(main ${BB})
```

I have got a lot of unresolved external symbols then.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774593/cmake-link-to-external-library

Comment: I do the same but it doesn't work for me

Comment: "it doesn't work" is a terrible diagnostic. Show the actual full linker commandline and any errors.

Comment: "I have got a lot of unresolved external symbols then." - We could only *guess* what kind of the unresolved symbols you got. Please, show (add to the question post) the **exact error message** you got. If there are many error messages, then make sure to provide at least the very **first** one. See also [ask].

Answer (score 2):

Don't hardcode paths to external libs.

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)
project(foo)

add_executable(bar ...)

find_library(libA NAMES A REQUIRED)
find_library(libB NAMES B REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(bar PRIVATE ${libA} ${libB})
```

```
cmake -S . -B build -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH="<path/to/libA/folder>;<path/to/libB/folder>"
```

Though, it would be far more robust if these two external libraries could provide a CMake config file with imported targets.

Comment: I do and it say "Can't open file 'A.lib'"

Comment: BTW I'm using MSVS2019

Comment: Works fine for me, clear your cache or explain exactly what you have done during cmake configuration & build